# Why be changed BMFace address with it's object MESH mode changing?

Tags: blender, bpy

I am working modeling by Blender 3D.
And i use BMesh.

And i save address of BMFace to variable (sel_f) in EDIT mode.

And i get out EDIT mode. and enter OBJECT mode.

And i again enter EDIT mode with BMesh.

And i call sel_f variable with "sel_f.select = True"

But i receive error message "BMesh data of type BMFace has been removed."

So i reDefined bm.

But old sel_f with new sel_f variable not same address.

Why not same?

**Look at the below example script.**

```
>>> import bmesh
>>> 
>>> obj = bpy.context.active_object
>>> me = obj.data

>>> bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
>>> 
>>> sel_f = bm.select_history[-1]
>>> 
>>> sel_f
〈BMFace(0x1E2918B0), index=2, totverts=4〉


Change MESH mode to "OBJECT mode" by manually. not by bpy script as below.
#  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")



again Change MESH mode to "EDIT mode" by manually. not by bpy script as below.
#  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")


>>> sel_f    #  i know that this is normalcy.
〈BMFace dead at 0x0DBE2F68〉



>>> bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
>>> sel_f = bm.select_history[-1]
>>> sel_f
〈BMFace(0x10FD3698), index=2, totverts=4〉     # Why not Same with above a address of BMFace?
```

Answer (score 1):

`object.data` stores the objects mesh data, when you switch into edit mode the mesh data is copied to a different structure for editing, when you switch back to object mode the edit mesh is copied back to `object.data` and the edit mesh is destroyed. Going back to edit mode creates a new copy of the mesh for editing so any previous data locations will no longer point to the current mesh data.

The same process is done whether you manually switch modes or use a script.